# Inner Join tables between a date range in QlikView

Tags: inner-join, qlikview

How can I accomplish an inner join between two tables via a date field which ranges between two values in QlikView?

In SQL this is possible with something like:

```
INNER JOIN TableA ON (TableA.Dates BETWEEN TableB.Start_Date AND TableB.End_Date)
```

In QlikView I have something like this:

```
DatesData:
LOAD * Inline [  
Test_Date 
    11/1/2013 
    12/1/2013  
    1/1/2014  
    2/1/2014  
    3/1/2014  
    4/1/2014  
    5/1/2014  
];

PersonData:
LOAD * Inline [  
ID, Start_Date, End_Date
    1,   12/1/2013, 2/1/2014 
    2,   1/1/2013, 3/1/2014 
    3,   2/1/2014, 4/1/2014  
];
```

I need to create a table like this:

```
 ID, Dates
 1, 12/1/2013  
 1, 1/1/2014  
 1, 2/1/2014 
 2, 1/1/2014 
 2, 2/1/2014
 2, 3/1/2014
 etc.....
```

How can I accomplish a join like this?

Answer (score 2):

The answer depends on whether you have a large range of values in your `PersonData` table because if you only have a few, you could probably get away with using an `if` statement if the ranges are fixed and do not change between reloads.

However, for more than five entries this becomes unweildly. In this case, there is an equivalent to SQL's `between` operator in QlikView called `IntervalMatch`. It behaves slightly differently to `between` since you cannot call it in an expression, but the principles are the same.

The below script uses `IntervalMatch` to match the ranges in `PersonData` to the date in `DatesData` by creating a link table. IntervalMatch tends to create synthetic keys/tables when left to its own devices, this is why we then follow up the inner join with another join into `DatesData` from `PersonData` (try leaving the second join out and viewing how the tables are linked).

Finally we drop `PersonData` as all the required fields are already in `DatesData`.

The only side-effect of this method is that you then have `Start_Date` and `End_Date` in your main table. However, you can quickly remedy this by adding a `DROP FIELDS Start_Date, End_Date` line to your script.

```
DatesData:
LOAD * Inline [  
    Test_Date 
    11/1/2013 
    12/1/2013  
    1/1/2014  
    2/1/2014  
    3/1/2014  
    4/1/2014  
    5/1/2014 
];

PersonData:
LOAD * Inline [  
ID, Start_Date, End_Date
    1,   12/1/2013, 2/1/2014 
    2,   1/1/2013, 3/1/2014 
    3,   2/1/2014, 4/1/2014  
];


INNER JOIN (DatesData)
IntervalMatch (Test_Date) 
LOAD 
    Start_Date,
    End_Date
Resident PersonData;

JOIN (DatesData)
LOAD
    *
RESIDENT PersonData;

DROP TABLE PersonData;
```